# initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle but subtitle not showing

Tags: xcode

Am trying to run the following code for a table with initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle but the subtitle is not showing. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize listData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sleepy", @"Sneezy", @"Bashful", @"Happy", @"Doc", @"Grumpy", @"Dopey", @"Thorin", @"Dorin", @"Nori", @"Ori", @"Balin", @"Dwalin", @"Fili", @"Kili", @"Oin", @"Gloin", @"Bifur", @"Bofur", @"Bombur", nil];
    self.listData = array;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.listData = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.listData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;

    if (row < 7)
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Mr. Disney";
    else
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Mr.Tolkien";
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return cell;
```

Should be the last line. It returns before setting the `detailTextLabel`'s `text` property.

Also, you should have received a warning from Xcode about "unreachable code."